# How to remove quotation marks in Table list

Tags: list-manipulation, import, string-manipulation

I have `Import` a `.txt`

```
Data = Import["files.txt", "Table"];
```

But the Data have the following format, I Cann't get the first column of `Data` eg. `a,b,c`, how to get rid of quotation marks in `Data`?

```
{{"a,10,20"}, {"b,10,20"}, {"c,10,20"},{"...and so on"}}
```

I have change the Import format like `Data, Elements` but all fails.

Any comments will be much appreciate!

Comment: Can you share a minimal example of the file in plain text form? While the answer by *kglr* es excellent, I think it would be nice to have a way to directly interpret the data while importing.

Comment: @rhermans yes, the minimal example is the Data list in the post, files.txt is very big. The answer by kglr is very helpful, thank you for comments!

Comment: No, what you have in the post is how the data looks like after importing it, not before. Am I wrong?

Comment: @rhermans right, I have import the .txt data by Import[files.txt, “Table”], the result data has quotation marks. I have try different Import format like “Elements” “Data” but all fails, maybe my txt files have an issue.

Comment: Why don't you share the raw data that we are asking for? Try to make it easier for us.

Comment: @rhermans, thank you! I think three raw is enough, eg. `{"a,10,20"}, {"b,10,20"}, {"c,10,20"}` ,  after have an idea, I should do the rest by myself.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
data = {{"a,10,20"}, {"b,10,20"}, {"c,10,20"}, {"a,1,1"}};

ReplaceAll[{s_String} :> ToExpression @ StringSplit[s, ","]] @ data
```

> ```
> {{a, 10, 20}, {b, 10, 20}, {c, 10, 20}, {a, 1, 1}}
> ```

Comment: Answer is very useful, thank you so much!

Comment: why we need `ToExpression`? I have try `ReplaceAll[{s_String} :> StringSplit[s, ","]] @ data` it still works.

Comment: @Ben, the results _look_ the same because string quotes are not displayed in output cells. Copy the output from `ReplaceAll[{s_String} :> StringSplit[s, ","]] @ data` and paste in an input cell, to the same for `ReplaceAll[{s_String} :> ToExpression @ StringSplit[s, ","]] @ data` and compare.

Comment: Thank you, I see, if not have `ToExpression`, the output is a string. But if the `data = {{"12:30,10,20"}, {"1:30,10,20"}, {"14:30,10,20"}};` ,when elements has a colon,  `ToExpression` will have an issue `Invalid syntax in or before "12:30"`, how can deal with this kind data list?

Comment: maybe I can use `ReplaceAll[{s_String} :> StringSplit[s, ","]] @ data` and then use `ToExpression ` to the other number element. I have try it and works.

Comment: you can also do `ReplaceAll[{s_String} :> (If[SyntaxQ@#, ToExpression@#, #] & /@ 
     StringSplit[s, ","])]@data`

Answer (score 2):

```
data = {{"a,10,20"}, {"b,10,20"}, {"c,10,20"}, {"a,1,1"}};

out1 = ToExpression@StringSplit[#, ","] & @@@ data

out2 = Map[Sequence @@ ToExpression@StringSplit[#, ","] &, data]
```

> {{a, 10, 20}, {b, 10, 20}, {c, 10, 20}, {a, 1, 1}}

Comment: Thank you give me another concise solution, I will compare  the speed of these method in big files data processing. Thank you again for such a good answer!

Answer (score 2):

```
list = {{"a,10,20"}, {"b,10,20"}, {"c,10,20"}};
```

Using `ImportString`

```
ToExpression @* ImportString @* ToString /@ list
```

{{a, 10, 20}, {b, 10, 20}, {c, 10, 20}}

Using `Cases`

```
Cases[list, x_ :> Splice @ ToExpression @ StringSplit[x, ","]]
```

{{a, 10, 20}, {b, 10, 20}, {c, 10, 20}}